# Check element against querySelector? (using native methods, not JQuery)

Tags: javascript, native-methods

I have an Element. I would like to check whether it meets a particular query, eg ('.someclass') in the same kind of style as querySelector.

This isn't as easy as it sounds. [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) and [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector) only work on **descendents** of the element in question. Not the element itself.

```
var p = document.querySelector('p')
```

Note: The line above is for illustration purposes only. In real life, I've actually found the element by some other means.

```
p.querySelector('p')
```

Returns `null`. Because querySelector only operates on descendents.

I could do:

```
p.parentNode.querySelector('.someclass')
```

But that would return the first child of the element's parent, which may be a different element. This code would fail, for example, if 'p' was the second child of the parent.

**How can I check if an element itself meets a query?**

Comment: `querySelector` operates on descendants, not children.

Comment: @Asad: Children and descendants are generally used interchangeably, much in the same way that parent and antecedents are. If you really like I can change the terminology.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be useful: why can't you just query the `className` or `Attributes` of the given Element?

Comment: @KooiInc I could indeed write something that checks className, ID, Attributes etc. But the resultant code would seem like a copy of something that already exists in the form of querySelector.

Comment: Well, the alternative looks more expensive: one way or another you'll have to loop a collection of Nodes and compare them to the given node to be sure you're operating on the right node. Having the node already available, querying its attributes/properties seems more obvious. One *can* drive a nail into wood using a screw driver, but a hammer is more suitable.

Comment: @KooiInc Since it's a fairly common problem I guessed there was a native method to take care of this without unnecessarily referring to extra nodes or rewriting the syntax for querySelector. And there is - see the answers.

Comment: It's ok with me ofcourse, and I like the [prefix]MatchesSelector approach, but using it you have to check for the right method (or prefix) to use before being able to apply it. Still looks a bit like a screwdriver to hammer a nail ;)

Comment: @KooiInc It's a prefixed hammer :^).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`matches()`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api2/#matches) method.

Support can be found at http://caniuse.com/matchesselector

---

<strike>But since it is still a draft, all browsers implement it with a prefix</strike> (*it was a draft in 2012*)

- `element.msMatchesSelector( selector )` (IE)
- `element.mozMatchesSelector( selector )` (mozilla)
- `element.webkitMatchesSelector( selector )` (webkit)
- `element.oMatchesSelector( selector )` (Opera)

Comment: written in 2022, it's a standard now with 96% support. https://caniuse.com/matchesselector

Answer (score 3):

Additionally: a helper to use the `MatchesSelector` in major browsers

```
function matches() {
  var el = document.querySelector('body');
  return ( el.mozMatchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector ||
           el.oMatchesSelector   || el.webkitMatchesSelector || 
           {name:'getAttribute'} ).name;
}
//=> usage
var someP = document.querySelector('p');
   ,rightClass = someP[matches()]('.someclass');
```

Still, `/someclass/.test(someP.className)` would be shorter here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, given element `e`, to check if it matches a selector you would use:

```
var check = false;
var c = e.parentNode.querySelectorAll('selector');
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    if (c[i]==e){
        check = true;
    }
}
```

A more concise, but somewhat hacky solution is:

```
var c = e.parentNode.querySelectorAll('selector');
var check = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(c,e) != -1;
```

NOTE: `check` indicates whether or not the element matches the selector.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2vX3z/

Comment: The reason anyone would wish to check an element against a selector is because they found the element via some other means. In my case I'm building a function to find which of an elements parents, if any, match a particular selector.

Comment: @nailer I've added a demo to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not in all browsers, but this might be helpful: http://caniuse.com/matchesselector

Example usage (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.mozMatchesSelector) page);

```
<div id="foo">This is the element!</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById("foo");
    if (el.mozMatchesSelector("div")) {//or webkitMatchesSelector("div") in webkit browser or msMatchesSelector("div") in IE9/10
      alert("Match!");
    }
  </script>
```

Supose the only other way is to run `querySelector` and loop through all items testing if it is the same as one you already have.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want. MDN docs are at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.mozMatchesSelector .

Comment: Race you to find the MDC docs? - sorry, I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Do you need MD**N** docs page? Link to it availale on a page I provided a link to

Comment: MDN, ahem. I found the link myself. Edit: ah, so many great answers!